# How to iterate all item at once in python list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

let's say i have list

```
strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]
```

when I = 0 , then I want

```
d,r,c
```

when I = 1, then I want

```
do,ra,ca
```

when I = 2, then I want

```
dog,rac,car
```

like that
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

## First Part

#### 1.

```
strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]

l = 0
for a in strs:
    print(a[:l+1],end=' ')
```

Output

```
d r c
```

---

### Explanation.

1. First loop through all the strings in the list.
2. Then print the string only to the `l` index, I use `l+1` because the end is excluded.
3. Means If you run `print('hello'[0:3])` it will give all strings to the index `0` to `2` not `3`/
4. set `end=' '` so it will not ends with a new line.

---

#### 2.

```
strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]

l = 0
lst = [a[:l+1] for a in strs]
print(*lst) # here *lst is same as print(lst[0],lst[1],...,lst[n])
```

Output

```
d r c
```

---

## Second part

#### 1.

```
strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]

for l in range(min(len(a) for a in strs)):
    for s in strs:
        print(s[:l+1],end=' ')

    print()
```

Output

```
d r c 
do ra ca 
dog rac car
```

#### 2.

```
strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]


for l in range(min(len(a) for a in strs)):
    print(*[s[:l+1] for s in strs])
```

Output

```
d r c 
do ra ca 
dog rac car
```

---

### Explanation for `min(len(a) for a in strs)`

1. Here inner comprehension(`len(a) for a in strs`) generates a list with the value as the length of the string inside the list.
2. Then `min(len(a) for a in strs)` returns the lowest number from the above list.

**I hope my explanation is clear. If not please ask me in the comments.**

Comment: I want to iterate in the range of min value in the list here let's say dog or car,  so next time iteration it should return me 2 characters and then 3 character till min item length

Comment: Instead of `l = 0`, you could generate `l` with `for l in range(min(len(w) for w in strs)):`

Comment: @PrajapatiYash Can you explain to me or can you give some samples of input and output?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the minimum length and then loop through each size up to that length.

```
strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]

for l in range(min(len(w) for w in strs)):
    print(",".join(s[:l+1] for s in strs))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]
def func(arr,n):
    w=""
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if n<=len(arr[0])-1:
            w+=(arr[i])[0:n]+" "
        else:
            w+=arr[i]+" "
    return w;
print(func(strs,2))
```

Keep on adding sliced portions of each string via loops,If the value of "l" [the variable you used to refer to the final pos] were to exceed the length of the string, the string would be added as a whole. (at least that's how I would handle that case).